# In linux how to join 2 files

Tags: linux, shell, join, sed, awk

I have 2 files file_A and file_B. The file file_A contains file name and then after space the code line. **This code line can have random kind of characters say blanks,: etc. It looks like this. Please note that the code line in the file is not surrounded by (). This was only for illustration purpose.**

**bash$ cat file_A**

```
file_name1 (code line a)
file_name1 (code line b)
file_name2 (code line c)
file_name2 (code line d)
file_name2 (code line e)
```

The file file_B contains the file_name along with frequency in file_A

**bash$cat file_B**

```
file_name1 2
file_name2 3
```

**I want output as: (frequency,file_name,code_line)**

```
2 file_name1 (code line a)
2 file_name1 (code line b)
3 file_name2 (code line c)
3 file_name2 (code line d)
3 file_name2 (code line e)
```

**bash$ join -1 1 -2 1 file_B file_A > file_C**

**I get file_C as (I get join fields as 1st field)**

```
file_name1 2 (code line a)
file_name1 2 (code line b)
file_name2 3 (code line c)
file_name2 3 (code line d)
file_name2 3 (code line e)
```

**How do I get the frequency field in the 1st field?.**

I know that with join I can use -o format and mention what fields and in what order I want in the output. But how do I say that put all in the code line (which can contain anything, so no delimiter as such) as such

Thanks,

Comment: Please edit your question and use the 101010 button in the editor to preserve the formatting of the the file snippets

Comment: This question is resolved. I can use snippet from: #!/bin/ksh

awk ' {
for (i=4; i<=NF; i++)
printf("%s ", $i)
printf("\n") # CR at end of line
} ' mydatafile

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and then accept it.  This way other users coming from Google can clearly see what the solution is.

Comment: Since you've found an answer to your own question, post it as an answer, not as a comment. This will allow people to upvote it (if they like it) or critique it (if they don't). This also makes your answer more readable to other people who might have a similar question. You can mark your own answer as accepted after a delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
join file_B file_A | awk '{t=$1; $1=$2; $2=t; print}' > file_C
```

Answer (score 1):

Note join doesn't support specifying a range of fields in the output format, so the following is a bit hacky, but does support up to 8 spaces in the "code line"

```
join -o 1.2,0,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9 file_B file_A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's#([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (.*)#$2 $1 $3#g'
```

Note: Maybe you will have to escape the normal brackets with backspaces to make it work.